# Running Java main class using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, process, processbuilder

A few months ago I created a small Gradle plugin that started up a Java application on the background. While this was working fine in the past it doesn't anymore and I am perplexed as to why it's not.

The launcher seems to be working fine under Windows but fails to the same thing under Linux. When it attempts to run the command in question which is this:

```
/home/aris.kourtesas/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.242.hs-adpt/jre/bin/java -cp "/home/aris.kourtesas/Projects/marketing-server/classes:/home/aris.kourtesas/Projects/marketing-server/classes/*" -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dads.net.port=17770 -Dads.db.user=marketing_int -Dads.db.pwd=marketing_int -Dads.marketing fts.marketing.server.WebServer
```

It fails with the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class fts.marketing.server.WebServer`

However when I copy paste the command and run it on a shell directly it works just fine. I am very confused and to be honest I do not what should I do. All the files are present and the classpath is correct yet it says that the main class I'm trying to invoke cannot be found.

For referenced this is the code that creates the launch command:

```
if (isWindows()) {
        builder.append("CMD /C START /B ")
    }

    builder.append(java() + " -cp " + classpath() +
            " -XX:+UseParallelGC " +
            "-Dads.net.port=${MARKETING_IT_APPSERVER_PORT} " +
            "-Dads.db.user=${MARKETING_IT_DB_USERNAME} " +
            "-Dads.db.pwd=${MARKETING_IT_DB_PASSWORD} " +
            "-Dads.marketing " +
            (MARKETING_IT_DB_HOST ? "-Dads.db.host=${MARKETING_IT_DB_HOST} " : '') +
            (MARKETING_IT_USER_HOME ? "-Duser.home=${MARKETING_IT_USER_HOME} " : '') +
            "fts.marketing.server.WebServer")
    if (!isWindows()) {
        builder.append(" &")
    }
```

And this is the part of code that creates and starts the process in question:

```
private def static createProcess(String directory, String command) {
       new ProcessBuilder(command.split(' '))
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .directory(Paths.get(directory).toFile())
                .start()
    }
```

Can you please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason *most likely* is some whitespace in your created command on a place you dont controll (e.g. usernames/userhomes/password) (log your command after split and see what happened).

Splitting on whitespace is such an fragile approach, you should **never** use it.  Using a string list in the first place is the way to go. Either use `["sh -c", "all your shelisms work here, even &"]` -- or use `[java() , '-cp', classpath(), ...]` (no quoting, no escaping, ... is needed here (only for your groovy strings))

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually the problem was caused by the fact that the passed in classpath was quoted. Removing the quotes resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this as the issue has been resolved. For some reason quoting the classpath was causing the command to fail when attempted to run in Linux.

Removed the quote from the classpath (conditionally for Linux) and the problem was resolved.